# Removed pendrive when restart option came after installing

Tags: system-installation, system

So I was installing Ubuntu the restart option popped out then I removed the pendrive before clicking restart then whole screen got blanked then I force shutdown my laptop from power button & booted ubuntu its working fine

Should I reinstall it?

Comment: WHY!! If it works why would you do that?

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details (and Ubuntu is available with different ISOs, installer & options; where we know none of those specifics).   It'll generally be *safe*, but I'm' assuming the restart option you're talking about is the one post `umount` of the media (where screen shouldn't blank) and not the one before the `umount` was performed (*suggesting you to restart to test new system or continue using existing)*. Both are likely full & correct installs; if it's the pre-umount you may have a failure to boot due to unclean file-system; but adjust for your *unstated* ISO

Comment: yes i've tested it for whole day it works fine...tweaked some things all s good for now

Answer (score 0):

The restart option popped up indicates that you have finished installing Ubuntu and prompts you to do a proper restart in order to exit from the Ubuntu installer. Ubuntu should be able to run OK even if you didn't restart it properly, similar to what happens when the operating system freezes and the user has no way to turn off the computer except by holding down the power button. If Ubuntu is running fine I wouldn't worry about reinstalling it.